# Different behavior of consteval in GCC and MSVC (not work)

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

class ClassT
{
public:
    consteval static size_t GetSize()
    {
        return sizeof(int);
    }

    void Resize()
    {
        _Data.resize(GetSize(), 0);
    }

    std::vector<uint8_t> _Data;
};

int main()
{
    ClassT Object;
    Object.Resize();

    return 0;
}
```

GCC compiles it successfully, but MSVC gives the following error:

```
error C7595: 'ClassT::GetSize': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
```

Am I missing something? Or is it really an MSVC bug?

Compilers version: `x86-64 gcc 10.2` and `x64 msvc v19.28`. ([Link to godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GfsMYb))

Comment: This is definitely a MSVC bug

Comment: [Reduced](https://godbolt.org/z/bj7KjM). This is surely an MSVC bug.

Comment: @Barry and AndyG. Thanks for the comment, I will report the bug to the MSVC developers.

Comment: They probably know already as the inane consteval was added 19.27 -> 19.28

Comment: @ÖöTiib Yes, I found an existing report about this bug ([Link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1224555/problem-with-consteval-function.html)). Next time I will search more carefully before asking questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an MSVC bug. It might even be the same as this existing one- [#1224555](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1224555/problem-with-consteval-function.html).

Minimal example:

```
consteval int test() { return 0; }

int main() {
    return test(); // error C7595: 'test': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
}
```