# Cannot use consteval functions inside initializer list on MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, consteval

Consider that minimized code snippet:

```
#include <vector>

class Bar
{
public:
    constexpr Bar() {}
};

consteval Bar foo()
{
    return Bar();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Bar> bars{ foo(), foo() };
}
```

This doesn't compile on latest MSVC compiler (Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3.3), but does on Clang or GCC.

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xn4rq6Gdo)

Is the code somewhere ill formed, or it is a bug in MSVC?

Comment: I think (but I'm not positive) that since you are using an STL container (vector) to store a custom type (Bar), the problem is that no copy (or move) ctor is defined (the call `foo()` returns an rvalue).

Comment: @RonaldSouza Possibly, but I doubt, since my original failing code was not using a STL container, and original `Bar`
 class was copyable.

Comment: @RonaldSouza - Those operations are implicitly defined. There is nothing here to supress their generation.

Comment: Duplicate? [Different behavior of consteval in GCC and MSVC (not work)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65396085/10871073)

Comment: I'm 99% certain it's a gap in MSVC's implementation. Not near a PC to verify comfortably, though...

Comment: ... the answer to the suggested dupe has a link to an MSDN blog that claims the issue is fixed, though. Seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica (and prapin): I see. Good point.

Comment: @AdrianMole Maybe the same original bug source, but it seems that current MSVC compiles the snippets in linked question, so not completely a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like this is indeed a bug in MSVC.

Therefore I filled in a bug report on Visual Studio Community.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-use-consteval-functions-returning/10145209

Comment: In my Visual Studio 2022, gave compile error `error C7595: 'foo': call to immediate function is not a constant expression`